# Call custom event on button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

I am trying to create my own webserver, which can parse custom asp.net web controls.
I have the following task: server needs to call event, which is declared in C# code when html button is clicked?

So, the question is: how is it possible to call distinct C# event when html button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add attribute `runat="server"` in html button and then handle the server click event. Please see the sample below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton btn = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton();
        btn.ID = "myID";
        btn.ServerClick += new EventHandler(someFunc);

        // you can add your button to some other parent control or to form
        myCustomPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

protected void someFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```